# Learning Vim, why start with "." parameter?

Tags: vim

What is the difference between starting Vim with `vim` and starting it with `vim .`?

Comment: Why not try them both and see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to the command is the file to load and edit.  In this case, the "." is the file.  Vim also has a few standard plugins that come preconfigured.  As you already noticed, the "netrw" plugin comes into play when you try to edit a directory.  It just gives you a nice filesystem browser that you can use to traverse through directories and then land your cursor on the filename you want.  You can press Enter to load the file.

It's merely for convenience for finding other files to edit, but can come as a surprise to newcomers.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.